# Getting dummy data as response to a valid authenticated api call in GCP

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform

I am currently trying to get percentage of cpu used by a VM instance using the following api in GCP:
       https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects//metricDescriptors?filter=metric.type="compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"

I have also enable the monitoring services, and have performed all the required authentications.

The api seems to be working but I am getting dummy data as response, I want to get real values of resource used, do I have to activate some metric which I don't know about? Any help will be appreciated .

Following is the response which I am getting from the api call:

[The respone from the above api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOAvf.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you received isn't dummy data but a description of the metrics. This is because you hit the `metricDescriptors` endpoints. Its usage is described in the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/browsing-metrics).

To get the actual data for a given metric, you need to hit the `timeSeries` endpoint and provide the necessary filters. You can see the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics) about reading metric data. You can also test it via the API Explorer [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list).